# FB.logout not working in IE8

Tags: facebook, firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, logout

I've integrated facebook login with my application and I want to logout the user from facebook when he logs out of my application. So I did the following:

```
<a href="<c:url value='/security_logout'/>" onclick="FB.logout();">Logout</a>
```

This works on Firefox and Chrome but doesn't work on IE8. In IE8 the user is logged out of the application but is not logged out of Facebook.
Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Have you tried to switch the IE8 to compatibility mode?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


        FB.init({
            appId: '205734987138498',
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true, // parse XFBML      
            oauth: true // enable OAuth 2.0
        });


    function handleSessionResponse(response) {
        // FB.XFBML.parse();
    }

    FB.getLoginStatus(handleSessionResponse);

//////you can optionally put the following in a seprate js file/////////

var Facebook = {}

Facebook.signout = function (url) {
    FB.logout();
    setTimeout('top.location.href = "' + url + '"', 2000);
}


</script>

<div onclick="Facebook.signout('http://www.uamplify.com');">Call your logout function now, click here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the exact same thing and also with the Android browser. Shahid's fix worked for me and then I realized another approach would be to put the redirect within the callback function like this:

```
function mysignout(url)
{
    FB.logout(function()
    {
        top.location.href = 'url'
    });
}
```

If you're like me, you probably figured FB.logout is just destroying a cookie or something but it appears to make some ajax calls (I guess to revoke authentication on the server) and has different execution times, especially on mobile devices using wireless networks.

2000 ms might not necessarily be enough time for the function to complete, or it could be more than necessary. The callback function executes once FB.logout has completed in every case.