# How can I logout by Facebook JS-SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to logout from Facebook from my application.
I tried to watch the other posts, but I didn't find what I need...

I have realised a link like`<a href="javascript: FB_LOGOUT()">LOGOUT</a>` and I have written a function, but it doesn't work... I tried this 3 methods, but none of them works.

```
function FB_LOGOUT(){
//FB.logout(function(response) {
//    window.location.reload(true);
//});

//FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
//  window.location.reload();
//});

//FB.logout(function()
    //{
    //    top.location.href = 'http://google.com/';
    //});
 }
```

Can you tell me how to logout from Facebook from my application? Please explain everything you think I'd better know, I'm really ignorant in this field... Thank you :)

Comment: read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197046/facebook-oauth-fb-getloginstatus-fb-logout-on-ie-chrome-firefox-android-b

Comment: I tried all the solutions in the answers, but none of them works.. I'm definetly doing something wrong, but what?
The example where I should use a facebook logout button doesn't work for me. If it can be usefull, I use Safari, but I'd like that the logout works on every browser..

Comment: Hi AleVale94, I am also facing the same issue. I have also tried varoius sol but not working, how did u fixed this issue??

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't write as comment, try this

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
  FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(null, 'unknown');

});
```

this refers to  [Facebook JS SDK FB.logout() doesn't terminate user session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817569/facebook-js-sdk-fb-logout-doesnt-terminate-user-session)