# FB.logout() called without an access token

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to log out of a website i've created with Facebook integrated.
Logging in works fine, but when I want to log out Firebug consistently gives me this error:

`FB.logout()` called without an access token.

I'm using the Facebook JavaScript SDK, and the code I've got to logout looks like this:

```
$(document).ready($(function () {
    $("#fblogout").click(facebooklogout);
}));

function facebooklogout() {
    FB.logout(function (response) {
    }
)};
```

This is the logout code specified at the [Facebook Developers Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/) just with a button being assigned the method on document.ready

Before this code I have the `FB.init()` method, that all runs fine.

If anyone's got a solution as to why FB.logout doesn't have an access token, it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To logout from the application which uses facebook graph API, use this JavaScript on the logout page just after the `<form>` tag:

```
window.onload=function()
{
    // initialize the library with your Facebook API key
    FB.init({ apiKey: 'b65c1efa72f570xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' });

    //Fetch the status so that we can log out.
    //You must have the login status before you can logout,
    //and if you authenticated via oAuth (server side), this is necessary.
    //If you logged in via the JavaScript SDK, you can simply call FB.logout()
    //once the login status is fetched, call handleSessionResponse
    FB.getLoginStatus(handleSessionResponse);
}

//handle a session response from any of the auth related calls
function handleSessionResponse(response) {
    //if we dont have a session (which means the user has been logged out, redirect the user)
    if (!response.session) {
        window.location = "/mysite/Login.aspx";
        return;
    }

    //if we do have a non-null response.session, call FB.logout(),
    //the JS method will log the user out of Facebook and remove any authorization cookies
    FB.logout(handleSessionResponse);
}
```

The code works and is live on my site.

Comment: Thank you Shadow for formatting my code. Please note that you need to place this HTML just after the <form> tag and before the javascript - <div id="fb-root">

Comment: Bill I was just wondering whether your solution would create some kind of loop, as the method handleSessionResponse is called from within itself.
(Just so you get an idea of skill and understanding, i'm a Junior Dev, only been learning for 6 months.)

Comment: Yes Martin. You are absolutely right. The function is recursive and is called until the the session returns a null value. The idea behind the recursive method was that it should keep on sending a 'logout' request to facebook until the user session on facebook is actually destroyed; since my testing showed that firing a single 'logout' request to facebook did not work every time (may be a fb api bug). The above code was only to make sure that the user logs out. I would appreciate if you could write a non-recursive method reusing the above code and post it as a alternative for SO users' referenc

Comment: Neat trick. I was able to adopt this code for my own app, by doing the same type of thing (looping the call to FB.logout() until the session was really destroyed)

Comment: Tricky thing. Thanks. Having the same problem until tried your solution.

Comment: A little update, the response no longer seems to send a .session. But response.status should be checked instead

Comment: I have Logout button in client side(an anchor button). When I click on it, how can I pass parameter to `handleSessionResponse` method on logout button click?

Answer (score 14):

I went for the less trivial solution:

```
    function facebookLogout(){
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                FB.logout(function(response) {
                    // this part just clears the $_SESSION var
                    // replace with your own code
                    $.post("/logout").done(function() {
                        $('#status').html('<p>Logged out.</p>');
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your code if wrong, if the user is not connected with facebook, you still want to disconnect him from you site (eg the `post('/logout')`)

Comment: @dorian thanks but that's my own code and no, it's not wrong. I clearly wrote "replace with your own code" above it. P.s. you can't make that judgement without seeing the code which executes in the `mydomain.com/logout` url

Comment: I mean, if somebody clicks the "logout" button, you want to clear their session even if they are not logged to facebook: https://gist.github.com/Dorian/f65a976f6b08739dcf83

Comment: @Dorian Oh right, well I was just clearing the session anyway (no one liked that the fb logout function was logging them out of facebook - as well as the app)

Comment: How do you do that? I tried and the user would still be connected with facebook (I deleted the fbsr_... cookies and sessions and stuff)

Comment: @dorian I'm just using the latest js api and that's what it does with the above code

Comment: `FB.logout` logs people out of their facebook account: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout

Comment: @Dorian It only logs them out of facebook if they logged in implicitly i.e they logged into facebook from an app's login flow and not by them logging in through from facebook.com

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out after so many tries.

Generally `response.authResponse.accessToken` contains token. So, its error about the accessToken not being there.

Think logically, where does that response come from in your code? Out of nowhere.

So, we need to get that response object from a function and get this working.
I don't know how it worked for others, but this worked for me.

**Just replace the code with this**

```
function logout(){
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    FB.logout(function(response){
      console.log("Logged Out!");
      window.location = "/";
    });
  });
}
```

What we do here is, get the login status if the user is logged in and get the corresponding response in return, which contains all the necessary tokens and data. Once this is fetched, the token is used to log out the user.

Comment: i also checked if there is any thing inside response.authResponse before calling FB.logout

Comment: Yeah! that adds another layer of precaution.

Comment: How does this "pass the response to the logout function"?
the response in the callback function argument for `FB.logout` is supposed to be passed by FB API after logout...

Answer (score 4):

I've tried something like this:

```
function fbLogout(){
    if(typeof FB.logout == 'function'){
        if (FB.getAuthResponse()) {
         FB.logout(function(response) { window.location.href = PROJECT_PATH + '/index/logout'; }); 
         return;
        }  
    };

    window.location.href = PROJECT_PATH + '/index/logout'; 
    return;  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Should be something more like this.  There was a change to the JS API where you have to use authResponse instead of just session.

```
//handle a session response from any of the auth related calls
function handleSessionResponse(response) {

    //if we dont have a session (which means the user has been logged out, redirect the user)
    if (!response.authResponse) {
        return;
    }

    //if we do have a non-null response.session, call FB.logout(),
    //the JS method will log the user out of Facebook and remove any authorization cookies
    FB.logout(response.authResponse);
}
```

Comment: that last line makes no sense, you need to pass a callback function (if you want) but why passing the response itself? just `FB.logout()` is enough. and what will call the `handleSessionResponse` function anyway? what is this mysterious `response`? the answer above clarifies this.

Answer (score 2):

The error says that you don't have an access token, you have to check for one using the FB.getAccessToken() function.

If there is no access token the function returns null. See example below:

```
   function facebooklogout() {
    try {
        if (FB.getAccessToken() != null) {
            FB.logout(function(response) {
                // user is now logged out from facebook do your post request or just redirect
                window.location.replace(href);
            });
        } else {
            // user is not logged in with facebook, maybe with something else
            window.location.replace(href);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        // any errors just logout
        window.location.replace(href);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

With Typescript this function do work fine ..

```
  signOutFacebook(): void {
    /*SIGN OUT USER FACEBOOK.*/
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        FB.logout(function (response) {
          console.log("Logged Out!");
        });
      } else {
        console.log("The person is not logged into your webpage or we are unable to tell. !");
      }
    });
  }/*FINAL 'signOutFacebook()'. */
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the access token with the FB.logout method, you need to ensure that you have obtained the access token during the login process and that it is available when you want to log out the user.

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
                
    if ( 'connected' === response.status ) {
        window.location.href = '/';
    } else {
        console.log( 'There has been an error.' );
    }
}, {
    access_token: accessToken
});
```