# Logging in and out with facebook, twitter in android application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my android application, i have two buttons "login with facebook" and "login with twitter".

### Login with facebook

```
        var my_client_id = "123412312323", 
        my_redirect_uri = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html", 
        my_type = "user_agent", 
        my_display = "touch"

        var authorize_url = "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?";
        authorize_url += "client_id=" + my_client_id;
        authorize_url += "&redirect_uri=" + my_redirect_uri;
        authorize_url += "&display=" + my_display;
        authorize_url += "&scope=publish_stream,offline_access";
        authorize_url += "&response_type=token"; 
        window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(authorize_url);
```

**using above url and child browser, i am asking user to login in Facebook.**

**using child browser's on location change method, i am accessing the Facebook token form the redirection url.**

I have logout button in my application, and i need to logout from facebook,

in logout method i have below facebook java script code

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
  alert(response.text);
});
```

But, i got error that saying **FB.logout() called without an access token**

i saw below stack overflow questions

[Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430474/fb-logout-called-without-an-access-token)

[Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744892/fb-logout-no-access-token-log-in-as-different-user)

FB.logout() works only if i used FB.login for logging into facebook, isn't it?

so, How to logout from facebook in my app?

Comment: so what exactly is your question??

Comment: so, How to logout from facebook using facebook api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used child browser to logging in with facebook as i showed above and for logging out i used same child browser for logging out of facebook.

```
        child_browser = window.plugins.childBrowser;
    child_browser.onLocationChange = function(loc){
        if (loc.indexOf("http://www.example.com") > -1) {
            window.plugins.childBrowser.close();
        }
    };
    child_browser.showWebPage("https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http://www.example.com&access_token="+facebook_token);
```