# User is automatically logged in after doing a log out, with Facebook-JavaScript-sdk login

Tags: facebook, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am able to smoothly log in the user into my site and get his details from facebook but I am not able to log him out.
On logging I am landing the user to the inner page for members. From there he presses the logout from my web site. On pressing that he is sent back to the front page, which in course gets reloaded.

I guess what is happening that the user who is logged in, when he presses the logout button he is redirected to the front page. But automatically the login event fires and he is logged in again.

I am using the following code.

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){  
    var button;
    if(document.cookie.indexOf("fbsr_myappid") > 0){// I am checking if the cookie value is set I am making status in FB.init() false. 
            var fb_status = false;
        }   
   else{
            var fb_status = true;
        }
    window.fbAsyncInit = function(){


        FB.init({ appId      : 'myappid',
            status     : fb_status,
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true 
        });
        showLoader(true);

        function updateButton(response) {
            button  = document.getElementById('fb-auth');
            if(response.authResponse) {
                FB.api('/me', function(info){
                    $.post("/web/register/faceBookRegistration",{data:info}).done(function(data){
                        if(typeof(data) != undefined){
                            window.location = "/web/login/loadFaceLogin"; // I am doing an ajax post to my login controller having loadFaceMember function. 
                        }
                    });
                    login(response, info); 
                });

                button.onclick = function(){
                // I think I should use the folowing code somewhere else
                    FB.logout(function(response){
                        logout(response); 
                    });
                };
            } else {

                button.onclick = function(){
                    showLoader(true);
                    FB.login(function(response){
                        if(response.authResponse) {
                            FB.api('/me', function(info){
                                login(response, info); 
                            });
                        } else {
                            showLoader(false);
                        }  
                    }, {scope:'email, user_birthday,user_about_me' });
                }
            }
        }
        FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);
    };

    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.async = true;
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.src = document.location.protocol +  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());

    function login(response, info){
        if (response.authResponse) { 
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            showLoader(false);
        }
    }
    function logout(response){
            FB.logout(function(response){
               console.log("User is now logged out."); 
            });
        showLoader(false);
    }



    function showLoader(status){
        if (status)
            console.log("Yes showLoader.");
        else
            console.log("Yes dont showLoader.");
    }
  });
```

On server side on pressing the logout button this following function is called in the logout controller.

```
function index(){
 $isSessionExp = true;

 if( $this->session->userdata('is_sess') )
  $isSessionExp=false;

  $login_session_id = $this->session->userdata('login_session_id');
  $this->login_model->updateLogoutTime($login_session_id);
  $this->session->sess_destroy();

 if($isSessionExp)
   redirect($this->url."/logout/session_expired");
 else
   redirect($this->url."/login");

 }
```

I guess if I am able to Link the above function in the logout controller with the following lines of javascript code.

```
      FB.logout(function(response){
           logout(response);
       }
```

my work will be done.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: this happens on Page Reload?  The page doesn't automatically reload when logout is clicked correct?

Comment: On logging I am landing the user to the inner page for  members. From there he presses the logout from my web site. After that he is again led back to the front page, so yes you are correct page reload is happening.I hope I have conveyed the scenario.

Comment: I have successfully performed Logging out of the Facebook API using this logout function.  May be worth a try..

`function logout() {
  FB.logout(function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
  });
}`

Comment: @G W. Thanks I tried but I guess that I should stop the logging event from firing again. I should put some condition to stop the logging based on a check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes what I had guessed was right. I needed to modify my logout function. Here is the modified function.

```
             function logout(response){
        console.log("From logout" + response);
        if(!response.authResponse){
            window.location = "/web/login/";
            return;
        }

           FB.logout(function(response){
               FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(null,'unknown');  
                 logout();
           });
        }
```

Thanks to @G W for pointing me in right direction.
Everyone feel free to comment and improve it. I would welcome that. My approach was based on this [FB.logout() called without an access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430474/fb-logout-called-without-an-access-token)