# Why this Facebook javascript-sdk login code is automatically logging the user again and again?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Here I am unable to keep a user logged out once the user presses the logout button from my site. He is redirected to the login page but updateButton function is called again with same credentials he is getting logged in again. I tried several ways but the problem persists. I guess I am not doing things rightly in updateButton function down here and also FB.logout() is not being done correctly, as I get the error "FB.logout called without an access token" in the console.
 The code is as follows:-

```
            $(function(){

           var button; 

           window.fbAsyncInit = function(){

            FB.init({ appId      : 'myAppId',

            status     : true,
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true
        });



         function updateButton(response) {// I am not sure I am doing it right here
             console.log("Update Button Fired.");
             console.log(response);

               button  = document.getElementById('fb-auth');

                if(response.status === 'connected')
                {
                    FB.api('/me', function(info)
                    {
                        login(response,info); 
                    });
                 } 
                else
                {
                     FB.login(function(response)
                     {
                            if(response.status === 'not_authorized')
                           {
                                FB.api('/me', function(info){
                                    login(response, info); 
                                });
                            } 
                            else
                            {

                            }  
                    }, {scope:'email, user_birthday,user_about_me' });
                }
            }  

          }

        FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);

        };

        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.async = true;
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = document.location.protocol +  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        })();

        function login(response,info){
            console.log('login Showloader called');
            if (response.authResponse) { 
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
              $.post("/web/register/faceBookRegistration",{ data:info,accessTokenValue:accessToken}).done(                       function(data){
                            if(typeof(data) != undefined){
                                window.location = "/web/login/loadViewFaceLogin";

                            }
                        });
            }


        }
        function logout(response){
           FB.logout(function(response){
              console.log("User is now logged out"); 
           });
        }

      });
```

Also I think my logout i.e

```
      function logout(response){ 
        FB.logout(function(response){
          console.log("User is now logged out"); 
    });
  }
```

is not correct. In the console it shows that FB.logout called without an access token. What could be the reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took the liberty to rewrite your code, keeping your bases:

```
   // File - fb-init.js

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : app_id,
            status     : false,
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true
        });
    };

    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
```

-

```
    // File - main.js

    $('#fb-login').on('click', function() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(responseStatus) {
            if (responseStatus.status === 'connected') {
                FB.api('/me', function(responseMe) {
                    if (!responseMe.id) 
                        return false;
                    var accessToken = responseMe.authResponse.accessToken;
                    $.post('/web/register/faceBookRegistration' {
                        data                : responseMe,
                        accessTokenValue    : accessToken
                    }).done(function(data) {
                        if (typeof(data) !== 'undefined')
                            window.location = '/web/login/loadViewFaceLogin';    
                    });   
                });
            }
            else if (responseStatus.status === 'not_authorized') {
                FB.login(function(responseLogin) {
                    FB.api('/me', function(responseMe) {
                    if (!responseMe.id) 
                            return false;
                        var accessToken = responseMe.authResponse.accessToken;
                        $.post('/web/register/faceBookRegistration' {
                            data                : responseMe,
                            accessTokenValue    : accessToken
                        }).done(function(data) {
                            if (typeof(data) !== 'undefined')
                                window.location = '/web/login/loadViewFaceLogin';    
                        });   
                    });
                }, {scope:'email, user_birthday,user_about_me' });    
            }
            else
                return false;
        });    
    });

    $('#fb-logout').on('click', function() {
        FB.logout(function(responseLogout) {

        });    
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Alexis 'ZeNy' Bize. I am very happy.

Comment: Why have you not set oauth : true in the fb-init.js

Comment: I never used the oauth var, and didn't see it in the current documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ - I think it is useless now :) (Maybe I'm wrong, but it works like a charm without). You're welcome, anyway you should improve my code, for example, I forgot the point if the user is not connected on Facebook, the FB.getLoginStatus will return false ;)

Comment: I felt its necessary after reading this.
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/07/21/updated-javascript-sdk-and-oauth-2-0-roadmap/

Comment: It was posted 2 years ago. Now, you get the same kind of responses without it ;)

Comment: Oh! Thanks. The case when user is not connected I need to put if (response.authResponse) {
            // connected
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
inside the FB.login function call. Isn't it?

Comment: The best way to do it is to replace « else if (responseStatus.status === 'not_authorized') » by « else », and remove the other one ;)

Comment: Yeah beacause in both cases we end up invoking the login call. So its better to handle them in one else block itself.

Comment: The way we are accessing the accessToken i.e.  responseMe.authResponse.accessToken can be made more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the *status* set to **true**. If the current user is already logged on Facebook, it forces his auto-login on the website.

Comment: One more thing that I am facing is that the popup is automatically coming when for the first time I am loading my site.
and i have tried setting status = false but it did n't worked

Comment: Also I think my logout i.e function logout(response){
           FB.logout(function(response){
              console.log("User is now logged out"); 
           });
        }
is not correct. In the console it shows that FB.logout called without an access token. What could be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, it's not a good idea to use the FB.logout(), except if you want to force the user to logout from Facebook (And not your website).

About the popup, I think it's because of FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton); which calls the function updateButton() on every page loads.

You should improve it through an onclick function.

Comment: Thanks 'Zeny'. But I had tried setting the status = false that did n't work for me.

Comment: About the pop button, button.onclick handler would be a good idea but I feel if I am able to set the if else condition correctly in my updateButton function then that also would be fixed. What do you say?

Comment: Will it be right if i put the                  FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(null,'unknown');  
                 logout();
under some other function and not FB.logout.

Answer (score 0):

As I saw this Post [FB.logout() called without an access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430474/fb-logout-called-without-an-access-token) it confirmed what I always was on my mind that my Logout is not being done properly. If that get done I would be okay.

Here is the logout function code which did it for me :-

```
                function logout(response){

              if(!response.authResponse){
                 window.location = "/web/login/";
                 return;
                }

               FB.logout(function(response){
                 FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(null,'unknown');  
                 logout(response);
              });
        }
```

As in the above link its been said that we should be keep sending logout request till its destroyed at the Facebook side. I made it a recursive call and the way out was when the the check confirmed it.

I am a noob and would only be glad if somebody working on the present solution builds a more elegant hack.

Thanks to 'ZeNy' too.