# issue in FB logout button

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, html

I have added a sample button for logging out from facebook in my app. but infortunately it does not seem to work as it usually work. i have even tried to implement a simple button to check but. but unfortunately it does not seem to work. any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Here is my code for logout:

```
        <input type="button" value="Logout" onclick="FB.Logout();">


       fbLogout(){ 
       if(typeof FB.logout == 'function')
       { if (FB.getAuthResponse())
       { FB.logout(function(response)
       { alert("you have logged out") });  
    return; } }; 

     alert("you have logged out"); 
     return; 
       }
```

i am getting an error as "FB.logout() called without an access token"

Comment: So what happens when you click it? Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: @pckill: it displays "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Logout'" error

Comment: I think the problem is that you need to type `logout` with lower case first letter. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/

Comment: @pckill: tried your response but error on consloe is like "FB.logout() called without an access token."

Comment: Did you actually login before logging out?

Comment: @pckill: yes of course. this is my login code http://jsfiddle.net/Ct7sV/3/show/  , and please do remember that once i have logged in i will be navigated to a new page.

Comment: In order to call `FB.logout` you need to init FB object and check for login status. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430474/fb-logout-called-without-an-access-token

Comment: @pckill: i have even added init and my code is function fbLogout(){
    if(typeof FB.logout == 'function'){
        if (FB.getAuthResponse()) {
         FB.logout(function(response) { window.location.href = PROJECT_PATH + '/index/logout'; }); 
         return;
        }  
    };

    window.location.href = PROJECT_PATH + '/index/logout'; 
    return;  
}

Comment: and now i get error as  "FB.logout() called without an access token"

Comment: Well, the message is pretty clear, the access token is apparently missing. Please add all the info from comments into your post, along with the login code, maybe someone will figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for Facebook context to load first. You can hide Log out button until you make sure that user is actually logged in to Facebook.

**CSS**

```
#logout-btn {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId : 'APP_ID',
        cookie : true,
        xfbml : true,  
        version : 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if(response.status === 'connected'){
            document.getElementById('logout-btn').style.display = 'block';
        }
    });
);
function logout(){
    document.getElementById('logout-btn').style.display = 'none';
    FB.logout();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="logout-btn" type="button" onclick="logout()" value="Log out" />
```