# Implementing Fb logout

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova

I'm working on hybrid application developed using phonegap/cordova. In this, I want to implement fb login and logout **without using FB javascript Sdk**

Fb login is successfully implemented. But I'm not able to implement logout.

**Here is the code of logout**

```
function logOut() {

    $.get("http://m.facebook.com/logout.php", {
            confirm: "1",
            next: "http://localhost/dogroups_fork/www/callback.html"
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log("FB :: ", data);
        });
```

But this isn't working, instead giving me the whole fb page in response. So what is the correct way to implement this by using **logout url provided by FB.**

Comment: to do FB logout you need a validate access token , otherwise you can't logout Facebook.

Comment: @SamArulRaj I've got the access token while login.. how do i use it for logout

Comment: You need to pass it as parameter named `access_token`.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430474/fb-logout-called-without-an-access-token