# Facebook Logout from my website in Laravel

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, laravel-5.3, facebook-php-sdk, laravel-5.4

When I click on logout... I get this exception in console:

> FB.logout() called without an access token.

Question: I already have Access token saved in Session and I have access to it in Client side also. I already checked this answer and could not understand that how can I invoke `handleSessionResponse` method and how what will be the response value when I click on logout button? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8430670/726802

**I have below code in layout page(master page).**

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '{!! env("FACEBOOK_APP_ID") !!}',
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : '{!! env("Facebook_Version") !!}'
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    };
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

**Below is the code in blade(content page)**

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li class="active"><a href="#" onclick="logout();">Logout</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {

            } else {
            }
        });
    }

    function logout() {
        debugger;
        FB.logout(function(response) {
            debugger;
            // user is now logged out
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Try initializing the JS SDK with parameters `cookie` and/or `status` set to true - so that it realizes that you already have a server-side login session.

Comment: ok, can u share any code ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init/v2.9

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Not yet. I am still waiting for an answer

Comment: You are using the official PHP SDK ? If so, wich helper are you using for the login ? Try this one https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper/5.0.0

Comment: Ia m using js sdk

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the access token is not persistent when change of page, try store the session in a cookie as said CBroe in a comment, something like this:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '{!! env("FACEBOOK_APP_ID") !!}',
        xfbml      : true,
        status     : true,
        cookie     : true,
        version    : '{!! env("Facebook_Version") !!}'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: How is it useful for logout?

Comment: @Pankaj Because the session is persistent through your application, and the access token would be available even if you change to other page to log out.

Comment: Where can I check the logout event?

Comment: @Pankaj What did you mean? where can you check if it does logout from FB?

Comment: I checked, This is merely doing init work. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus) to obtain the active access token maintained by [Facebook JS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript). And use the response to call [FB.logout](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout)

```
function fbLogoutUser() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response && response.status === 'connected') {
            FB.logout(function(response) {
                // needed for older versions of SDK
                FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(null, 'unknown');
                // reload to remove accessToken from browser cookies
                document.location.reload();
            });
        } else{
            // You are not logged in
        }
    });
}
```

Reloading the page after logout will remove current session's access token from the browser cookies.

Comment: In your original code I could see `FB.init`, `FB.AppEvents` and `FB.logout`, If FB is not undefined at that instance, it shouldn't be undefined here too.
Make sure you call it after the FaceBook JS SDK is initialized and FB is available.

Comment: This is the original problem. I am getting exception: FB.logout() called without an access token.